# Structure of AWS Chef Repository

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

AWS expects your Chef repository to contain cookbook directories in the root directory while the repository that is generated by Chef has a `cookbooks` directory for all the cookbooks (along with `data_bags`, `environments`, etc.)

How can we use the Chef generated repository structure in AWS?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. When you say "AWS" I think you are talking specifically about AWS OpsWorks, as you can use Chef any way you want outside of that. For OpsWorks, you use it via its API and Console tools.

Comment: The question is about the Chef repository structure. If you provide AWS OpsWorks a GitHub repo URL which uses the default Chef repository structure (which has directories for `cookbooks`, `data_bags`, etc) it does not accept it. That is, it does not see the cookbooks. It will give you an error such as `cannot find cookbook: apt`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this. OpsWorks has it's repo format documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workingcookbook-installingcustom-repo.html. Additionally you can't use roles or custom data bags with OpsWorks, you are expected to use the relevant OpsWorks or EC2 APIs or their custom data bag system.